# NullPointerException at int array in Java Project

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I am creating a method which will take int n as a parameter, convert a previously initialized String into an integer array, add 1 to each index n times, create a new char array from each increment of the int array via casting, then convert all n char arrays into new strings and print them to the screen.

Netbeans throws a NullPointerException in my current project, and I'm not sure why. Could someone explain why this error is present and what I ought to do to fix it?

Relevant Class: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gv02i1traulg8kp/StringShifter.java
Class containing Main Method: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ymon96ovv4c2lnf/CodeBreaker.java

Error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Project5.StringShifter.shift(StringShifter.java:35)
at Project5.CodeBreaker.main(CodeBreaker.java:18)

Comment: Please put the relevant code in the question, rather than in Dropbox. You should edit it to a *short* but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
    int[] a = null; 
    char[] b = null; 
    int r = 0; 

    for (int i = 0; i <= text.length(); i++) { 
        a[i] = text.charAt(i); 
    }
```

a is set to point to null, and then you try to assign a value to a[i] (which currently does not have a place in memory), which will give you a NullPointer.

Answer (score 3):

Look at your code:

```
int[] a = null; 
char[] b = null; 
int r = 0; 

for (int i = 0; i <= text.length(); i++) { 
    a[i] = text.charAt(i); 
}
```

`a` is null - you've explicitly set it to `null`. So

```
a[i] = text.charAt(i);
```

will fail with a `NullReferenceException` - it's bound to. You'd need to initialze `a` to refer to an array, e.g.

```
int[] a = new int[text.length()];
```

You *also* need to change your upper bound - as when `i` is `text.length()`, `text.charAt(i)` will throw an exception. So you want:

```
int[] a = new int[text.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) { 
    a[i] = text.charAt(i); 
}
```

It's not clear why you want an `int[]` at all though. It would be simpler to use:

```
char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    chars[i] = (char) (chars[i] + 1);
}
```

Also:

- There's no point in going over the loop multiple times - just add `n` instead of 1
- There's no point in creating a new string on every iteration; just do it at the end

Comment: `int[] a = new int[a.length()];` Your code is confused. I think you meant what you had previously written... `a[i] = new int[text.length()];`

Comment: @MirroredFate: Yup, just a typo - fixed. (Although it's just assigning to `a`, not `a[i]` - that bit was wrong before too!)

Comment: Oops, I missed that one too. Is `the loop loop multiple` also a typo? Because if not I am really confused.

Comment: @MirroredFate: Yes, it is. Again, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You define `int[] a = null` and never initialize it.

When you try to access it in `a[i] = text.charAt(i);` you get the `NullPointerException`.

You can solve you issue adding `a` initialization:

```
int[] a = new int[text.length];
```

Comment: `int[] a = null;` *does* initialize it - it initialize the variable to `null`.